# Display different value than options text in Dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have a data source which looks like this

```
$scope.NameList = [
 { id:1, name:'Thomas S.', short:'TS' }, 
 { id:2, name:'Paul F.', short:'PF' },
 { id:3, name:'Kate M.', short:'KM' }
]
```

I want my DropDown to display the property `name` as options, bind the `id` property to a model and display the the property `short` of the selected item. Is there a way to achieve that with `ng-options`?

Comment: Where do you expect the `short` property to be displayed?

Comment: And are you talking about `ng-selected` directive or about `select` html element ?

Comment: Whoops, I meant `ng-options` of course. I want the `short` property to be displayed after an option was selected.

Comment: Do you use AngularUi-Bootstrap ?

Comment: The only thing that is not possible based on your requirement is to have ng-model bind the id because it will be binded to the json object of the option. But the other two requirements are possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because it uses the HTML `select` component that is not able to distinguish between the displayed text in the dropdown and the shown value.

However you could build an own directive for implementing a similar behaviour, for example with a bootstrap dropdown menu.